# How to generalize an iterator to a certain type

Tags: c++, templates, generics, iterator, containers

Consider these two functions, which work well for a std::vector:

```
  int connectNode(GraphNode const& newNode,std::vector<GraphNode const*>::const_iterator beginCandidates, std::vector<GraphNode const*>::const_iterator endCandidates){
    int connections =0;
    for (auto iter= beginCandidates; iter!=  endCandidates; ++iter) {
      if(connectNodes(newNode,**iter)) ++connections;
    }
    return connections;
  }

  int connectNode(GraphNode const& newNode,std::vector<GraphNode>::const_iterator beginCandidates, std::vector<GraphNode>::const_iterator endCandidates){
    int connections =0;
    for (auto iter= beginCandidates; iter!=  endCandidates; ++iter) {
      if(connectNodes(newNode,*iter)) ++connections;
    }
    return connections;
  }
```

These functions work well for vectors but evidently not for any otehr container, e.g. a set. How could they be generalised. The only possible solution I can think of is with some quite ugly enable_if workaround. Is there a straight forward solution ?
Edit: 
To make it clearer: I want both functions, one for normal containers, one for pointer containers. The real logic happens inside connetNodes, which takes two references. (mind the ** in the first function)

Comment: Do you need to enforce that it **must** be an iterator to `GraphNode`?

Comment: @Drew Dormann: It should be either a GraphNode or a Graphnode const*. The Problem is that I need both, value and pointer. The type could also be left open at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was said, make the iterator type a template parameter - this solves the issue of generalizing the iterator itself. For differing between normal `GraphNode` values, and pointers thereof, you can just use overloading:

```
template<class T>
T& maybe_deref(T& v){ return v; }

template<class T>
T& maybe_deref(T* p){ return *p; }
```

And just call that in `connectNodes(newNode, maybe_deref(*iter))`.

Comment: Good Idea, especially the generic maybe_deref !

Answer (score 2):

Take the iterator as a template parameter, then you don't have to worry what kind of container you're iterating over.

```
template<class T, class Iter>
int connectNode( GraphNode const& newNode, 
                 Iter beginCandidates, 
                 Iter endCandidates )
{
  // ...
}
```

I don't see the other template parameter (`T`) being used anywhere in the function template, but I'm assuming your real code uses it somewhere.

Also, you can `static_assert` that the iterator points to a `GraphNode const*` using `std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type`

```
static_assert( std::is_same< typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type
                             GraphNode const *>::value,
               "Iterator must point to 'GraphNode const *'" );
```

**EDIT:**

In order to be able to accept iterators that point to either `GraphNode` or `GraphNode const *` leave the function template signature the same, but create 2 overloads for a helper that calls `connectNodes`

```
bool do_connectNodes( GraphNode const& newNode, GraphNode const *p )
{
  return connectNodes( newNode, *p );
}

bool do_connectNodes( GraphNode const& newNode, GraphNode& n )
{
  return connectNodes( newNode, n );
}
```

Now, within `connectNode` change the `if` condition to

```
if( do_connectNodes(newNode,*iter) ) ++connections;
```

and the correct overload will be selected depending on what the iterator is pointing to.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help since i want to accept both, an  iterator to value and an iterator to pointer and dereference in the case of the pointer.

Comment: Yes, the T was a left over from the full function, just removed it. Thanks for noting

Comment: @Martin Updated to allow both kinds of iterators. Sorry, but I didn't fully understand your question when I first read it.

Comment: Just got the same idea, from reading your question before the edit. I think this is the cleanest solution. Thx